# Does it make any difference if I choose the Bird or the Cage Brooch?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

As I was playing Bioshock Infinite today, I was greeted by this fellow and lady shortly after busting Elizabeth from the confines of that statue. They gave us the choice of two brooches. One of a cage, and one of a bird. I simply wasn't thinking that this might have any effect on the game when I went with what Elizabeth sounded most intrigued by. So now she is stuck with a cage on her neck. Not the nicest of symbolism...

**Does the brooch you pick for Elizabeth have any effect on the game or story line?**

> Note: **SPOILERS AHEAD.** Answers contain spoilers.

[image: Screenshot of Elizabeth offering brooches]

Comment: Nice of you to steal the screenshot I took for my question :-/ http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112994/does-it-make-any-difference-if-i-choose-the-bird-or-the-cage

Comment: @Django Reinhardt, If you like, I can hit the rollback button. My first reaction when it was added was to do that since I'd seen it in your question and felt like it was unnecessary and a bit thieve-y. I didn't since I figured the community knew better than I did.

Comment: I guess it's more @kip than you. I know it's only a screenshot, but I was surprised to see it here!

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt sorry, it didn't occur to me that you had taken the screenshot yourself. i assumed you had just found the picture somewhere on the internet. i was just trying to make the "original" as good as the duplicate, since your question was closed as a duplicate of this one. if you guys want to roll it back feel free

Comment: @Kip No problem. I think I got downvoted because someone thought I'd stolen it from this question, though *le sigh!*

Comment: @Aeo Would you prefer that answers be mostly hidden in spoiler markup/tags or not? I'm asking because [an answer of mine in this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/113125/4797) keeps getting downvoted and edited due to lack of spoiler markup. If you would prefer that answers have spoiler markup, I will allow [the most recent edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/113125/7) hiding most of my answer in spoiler markup, if not, I'll roll it back to how I would like my answer to look.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well, not directly, so don't worry about it.

**The point here is that you made a choice that you will remember and notice it later on.**

More information with *SPOILERS*, read only *AFTER FINISHING THE GAME*:

> Thanks to this choice you will almost immediately notice that the girl at the end is not Elizabeth since she doesn't have the brooch you selected for her. It was a nice touch by the game creators.

Comment: Thank you. That's a relief to hear. I haven't finished the game yet, so I've avoided the spoiler tag. I'll definitely be back after to check it :D

Comment: If they were really going for this, it would have been better if she was wearing the OTHER brooch.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt That is a matter of opinion. Personally (and I said this in another post) I think it makes more sense for them to remove the brooch entirely (as they did) if they are wishing to communicate that this is not "our" Elizabeth. Again, it's subjective.

Answer (score 6):

> Needless to say – **SPOILERS AHEAD!**

Like many other choices in the game, it has no effect on the gameplay whatsoever. However, the act of choosing a brooch has a significant bearing on the story.

In one of the final scenes, Booker will recognize that "Elizabeth" is not *the* Elizabeth he's been trying to rescue. A giveaway is that this Elizabeth will *not* be wearing the brooch that Booker chose for her.

[image: As Keanu Reeves would say, "Whoa!"]

Comment: Regarding spoiler tags/markup, please see this meta discussion: [Should answers on questions that ask for spoiler information be put in spoiler markup or not?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7128/4797)