# Does it make any difference if I choose the Bird or the Cage?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I was wondering, does choosing the Bird or Cage Pendant in Bioshock Infinite change the game in ANY way (aside from which pendant Elizabeth wears around her neck for the rest of the game)?

[image]

I've read some people say that they didn't notice any differences, but does anyone know for sure?

Comment: It changes the short dialogue between the gentleman and the lady immediately thereafter (about which one of them guessed right), but I suppose that's not what you meant.

Comment: +1 since this question is apparently found through google much more often than the other one (this one has a much better title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer: **No**. It seems to make no difference to the story or the characters :-/

Update:

An anonymous user offered the following:

*"I believe it changes the Gear that you find. When I picked the Bird I noticed that the Gear I picked up all complimented my firearms. But when I chose the Cage, I got gear that complimented my Vigors. I have played the game through like 6 times."*

I believe this wrong, however, as I've noticed that the gear you find seems randomised.